# How to toggle the visibility of a document element?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a label on my form like so:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPwPol" 
     runat="server"
     Visible="false">

  A bunch of text... 

</asp:Label>
```

In a method called by the `Page_Load` event (VB.net), I attach some JS event handlers with this:

```
    btnPasswordPolicies.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return mShowToolTip();")
    cmdPasswordPolicies.Attributes.Add("onmouseleave", "return mHideToolTip();")
```

Which are defined as such:

```
function mShowToolTip(aCtrl, aArg1)
{
    document.getElementById("lblPwPol").style.display = 'block';
    return false;

}

function mHideToolTip()
{
    document.getElementById("lblPwPol").style.display = 'none';
    return false; 
}
```

When my form loads, the label is not visible (correct).

When I click the label, I get an exception in my JS:

> Javascript runtime error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference

Which obviously means that `document.getElementById("lblPwPol")` returns null.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I feel like it's got to be something rally stupid, but I don't know JS at all.

I tried also switching out the `id="lblPwPol"` to be `name="lblPwPol"` instead, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: when you use asp.net controls, the id is different when the control is rendered in the html. your `id='lblPwPol'` is different in the html. so instead of using `document.getElementById('lblPwPol')` u can use `document.getElementById('"<%= lblPwPol.ClientID %>"')` and your code should work fine.

Comment: In case you try @Sushil's suggestion, you should use only one set of quotes: `document.getElementById('<%= lblPwPol.ClientID %>')`. But the real problem is the one reported by @Kris: the label is not in your HTML output because of `Visible="false"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you should remove visible="false" to the label, because of you make it visible false it won't load in Dom. And keep style="display:none"
Like this

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPwPol" 
 runat="server"
 Style="display:none">

  A bunch of text... 

   </asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing DOM elements with [ASP WebUI WebControl elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label(v=vs.110).aspx) (that are XML as well btw). Take a look at here how to access a Label control like yours: [How to access asp:label text property from code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692637/how-to-access-asplabel-text-property-from-code-behind)